# Converting time format from 3.5 to 3:30 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have data in SQL Server database in decimal format and I want to convert time HH:MM format.

For example:

```
3 to 3:00    
3.25 to 3:15
3.5 to 3:30
3.75 to 3:45
```

Thanks very much for any help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert decimal time to hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788283/convert-decimal-time-to-hours-and-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Harzio, See this version: you need to convert to datetime using this function `CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, 60*[time], 0), 108)`

Full mock up below:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE  ([Time] FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @tmp
SELECT 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3.25 UNION ALL  
SELECT 3.5  UNION ALL     
SELECT 3.75   

SELECT 
    [Time],     
    NewTime=CONVERT(CHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, 60*[time], 0), 108)
FROM @tmp
```

Results here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much @MEdwin. Your query result is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Multiply by 60 and add that number of minutes onto midnight:

```
declare @sample table (timeStoredWrong decimal(5,3))
insert into @sample (timeStoredWrong) values (3),(3.25),(3.5),(3.75)

select CONVERT(time,DATEADD(minute,60*timeStoredWrong,0)) as result
from @sample
```

Results:

```
result
----------------
03:00:00.0000000
03:15:00.0000000
03:30:00.0000000
03:45:00.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever, your query works but with some extra 0000..

Comment: @Harzio - you can specify `time(0)` rather than bare `time` if you don't want milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp ([time] DECIMAL(6,2))
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3)   
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3.25)   
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3.5)   
INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES (3.75)   

SELECT [time], CAST(CONVERT(TIME,DATEADD(SECOND, [time] * 3600, 0),108) AS TIME) FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @a money = 3.75;
SELECT FORMAT(FLOOR(@a)*100 + 60*(@a-FLOOR(@a)),'00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--set demo data here
Select * into #YourTable from
(SELECT 3.5 as atime union select 3.2833333333 union select 23.01666) dq;

--change string to float, multiply by 3600 to give seconds, add seconds
--to midnight date, format to HH:MM
SELECT atime, FORMAT(dateadd(s , round(3600 * CAST(atime as float),0) ,CAST('00:00:00' AS time)) ,N'hh\:mm') from #yourtable

--clear up demo data
drop table #yourtable
```

Comment: @Melebius - ok I added some comments - we're not here to teach SQL though, interpreting SQL that carries out a task is part of the job he's doing