# Decimal value to HH.MM conversion problem. 0.33333 Decimal value not showing as 00.20 minutes

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having an issue converting a decimal such as 0.33333, which needs to show as 20 minutes. Using the formula I have it is showing as 19 minutes. I hope someone can assist please. Thank you. Currently the code I am using example.

```
declare @value float = 0.3333333
select
Cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, Floor(cast(@VALUE as Decimal (10,2))))) 
            + '.' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, (cast(@value as Decimal (10,2)) - Floor(cast(@VALUE as Decimal (10,2)))) * 60.0)) as Decimal(10,2)) [hh.mm],
            cast(@value as money) [DecimalHours]
```

Comment: What happens if you keep more decimals, and skip floor?

Comment: Money data type for time values?

Comment: Well, that's because it's 19.999998 minutes and not 20. Probably you need to round instead of floor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert decimal time to hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788283/convert-decimal-time-to-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: Thank you for the link, the problem with this one is that when I am dealing with hours over 24 hours it doesn't show correctly. For example I may have 498.3333 as a figure which would then need to display as 498.20 ideally. Thank you I will try the rounding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 -- integer part      -- fractional part             -- final rounding
cast(floor(@value) + ((@value - floor(@value)) * 0.6) as dec(18,2))
```

Works for more than 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

Probably a lot easier when you use a date/time function:

```
SELECT FORMAT( DATEADD(n,ROUND(60.0 * @value,0) ,0) , 'HH:mm')
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't quite work for anything over 24 hours. So a figure like 498.08 returns as 18:05. This needs to show as 498.05. The below solution from dnoeth achieves this. Thank you again