# Getting the correct hour value with datediff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I'm trying to use the `datediff` function in SQL Server. I'm querying two datetime columns in the same table. I'm trying to get the results where I get hours and minutes in decimal points.

As an example I have this query:

```
Select 
    startdatetime, enddatetime, 
    datediff(minutes, startdatetime, enddatetim) / 60 as 'Hrs worked' 
from table1
```

The results will be something like:

```
startdatetime                      |  enddatetime                          |  Hrs. worked
2019-02-28 06:00:00.0000000 -08:00    2019-02-28 07:15:00.0000000 -08:00      1
```

Clearly the difference between startdatetime and enddatetime should be 1.25 not just 1.

Is there anyway to show the decimal value (1.25)?

I also tried:

```
Select 
    StartDateTime, EndDateTime, 
    Convert(decimal(3), (Datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime))) / 60 AS 'Hrs Worked' 
From Table1
```

and I do get the Hrs. worked as '1.250000', but I'm unable to drop the trailing zero.

If I use `decimal(2)` instead of `decimal(3)`, I get this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric

Any suggestions?

Comment: A trailing zero doesn't change the value of a number?

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @startdate DATETIME = '2019-02-28 06:00:00';
    DECLARE @enddate DATETIME = '2019-02-28  07:15:00';
    
    SELECT CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startdate, @enddate) AS DECIMAL) /  60 AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
```

maybe you also need this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788283/convert-decimal-time-to-hours-and-minutes) to properly format it.

Answer (score 0):

`DATEDIFF` returns an `INT` value (here: 75), and dividing that by `60` uses **integer** division, so you won't get any fractions of an int (basically answering the question: "how many times can '60' be completely contained in the value in question - here '75' - and that's just '1').

If you want the fractional hours - just divide by `60.0` to get "normal" decimal division:

```
SELECT
    StartDateTime, EndDateTime, 
    DATEDIFF(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0 AS 'Hrs Worked' 
FROM
    Table1
```

This will return the expected `1.25` as your value

Comment: Thanks guys (Jack Liu & marc_s), actually the solution was in combination to both your posting.  I had to define the decimal to be (10, 2) and divide by 60.0.  Without both solutions, the results will be a numeric with about five integer numbers (i.e. 1.25000).  By combining both solutions I finally got the result 1.25.  Thanks guys.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in combination from both Jack Liu & marc_s suggestion.

I needed to also define the decimal and explicitly set 60.0.

Here is an example of the correct format in what I am trying to do.

Select
StartDateTime, EndDateTime,
CAST(Datediff(minute, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) / 60.0 AS Decimal(10, 2))'Hrs Worked'
From Table1