# How to calculate hours and minutes from decimal numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, addition

working hours column values be like

```
2
5.3
7.45
0.5
0.3
2.05
```

Expected output
18.40   (18 Hours 40 Minutes)

**Explanation**

```
2 (2 hours)
5.3 (5 hours 30 mins) 
7.45 (7 hours 45 mins)
0.5 (50 mins)
0.3 (30 mins)
2.05 (2 hours 5 mins)
```

First add the numbers after the decimal point

**Should be 2 digits after decimal point**
(How to do this? it is float data type column it stores 5.30 as 5.3)

Digits after decimal point

```
00
30
45
50
30
05
----
160 (mins)
----
```

**Add Whole numbers**
2 + 5 + 7 + 2 = 16

160 mins --> 2 hrs 40 mins
**Expected answer is 18.40 (18 hrs 40 mins)**

<sub>Note: Some people comments regarding data type, this is an old table, I have not created this table and data type cannot be changed now.</sub>

Comment: I would have interpereted 5.3 hours to be 5hr 18m, 5hr 30m would be 5.5 hours?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert decimal time to hours and minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17788283/convert-decimal-time-to-hours-and-minutes)

Comment: So `5.3` (and all other examples) is actually not a decimal but a flawed string representation of `5:30`?

Comment: @Stu   5.5 -> 5 hours 50 mins

Comment: @Relax half (.5) of 60 minutes is 30 minutes

Comment: What would 5.7 represent then? 6 hours 10 minutes?

Comment: @Stu 0.5 means 50 minutes, 0.3 means 30 minutes

Comment: @ThomA I allow up to 59 after decimal part (I do this validation in front end)

Comment: I would suggest *float* is completely inapropriate (it usually is tbh) and you should be storing your hours and minutes as two separate entities - the task of summing the values is then simple. And `0.5` of *what* means 50 minutes? You're confusing the use of *decimals* vs just delimited data I think.

Comment: Do you have such validation in your *back end* though, @Relax ? Honestly, Id suggest storing something like 2 hours as the `int` value `120`, which would represent 120 minutes (as it seems you only need to be accurate to 1 minute). Storing these values as a `float` (a **terrible** choice) and using non-sensical values like `.5` representing 50 minutes, instead of half an hour is asking for all sorts of problems.

Comment: The reason for downvotes is in the tooltip, @Relax : "The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." It's unlikely you'll get more than that. If you want to be constructive, you should be asking how you can improve the question.

Comment: @ThomA The question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful
Then how did 3 people (so far) answer this question

Comment: Answering and up/down voting are completely different actions, @Relax , and are completely unrelated. As an example, it's very easy for a question to show absolutely no research effort but still be completely clear on the problem. A question asjking "How to I convert an `int` to a `varchar` in T-SQL." would be *very* clear, however, certainly would demonstate no research effort, and likely be deemed not helpful (as there's more than likely a duplicate).

Comment: At a *guess* as I can't read the minds of others, I'd guess the downvotes are due to lack of research; you've made no demonstration of your attempts or even what you didn't understand about materials you've read to help you solve the problem. As a lack of research effort is a reason to downvote, I would *guess* that's the reason for the (at time of writing) two downvotes on the question. A lack of research does not mean the question is unclear/unhelpful, but many users (and infact the [help]) expect those asking to actually *try* to solve a problem before they post on [so].

Answer (score 3):

Moving past the issue of storing not-a-decimal-or-float-value as a float, what you actually have are two separate data elements representing hours and minutes somehow munged into a floating point value.

Just dealing with the issue of taking the source data I would be inclined to cast it immediately to a string as otherwise you'll start running into all sorts of rounding issues as floats are *imprecise*.

You could try the following approach that first converts the values to a string via a decimal (to preserve a true decimal value) and then parses them into their two atomic values, from there you can simply sum and convert.

```
select
  Sum(h * 60 + m) / 60 hrs, 
  Convert(Int, Round((((Sum(h * 60 + m) / 60.0) %1) * 60), 0)) mins
from yourtable
cross apply(values(Convert(Varchar(5), Convert(Decimal(4,2), n))))s(s)
cross apply(values(Convert(int, ParseName(s, 2)), Convert(Int, ParseName(s,1))))t(h, m);
```

See [demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yrcHTbvx)

Comment: Its working, can you display the result as a single column like 18.40, if possible add below to the above query, don't change the current working query that would be helpful.

Comment: @Relax You could use *concat* to do that - like in this [amended fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wil0QAX6)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE WorkingHours (Hours FLOAT);
INSERT INTO WorkingHours VALUES (2), (5.3), (7.45), (0.5), (0.3), (2.05);

SELECT CONCAT(
    CONVERT(INT, SUM(FLOOR(Hours))) + CONVERT(INT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (Hours - FLOOR(Hours)) * 100))) / 60, '.',
    CONVERT(INT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (Hours - FLOOR(Hours)) * 100))) % 60)
FROM WorkingHours;
```

`SELECT CONCAT(...) FROM WorkingHours;`: This calculates and returns a concatenated string as the result. The calculations involve converting the working hours into a decimal time format (hours and minutes).

`CONVERT(INT, SUM(FLOOR(Hours)))`: This part calculates the sum of the integer part of the working hours for all rows. It uses the FLOOR function to extract the integer part of each value.

`CONVERT(INT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (Hours - FLOOR(Hours)) * 100))) / 60`: This part calculates the sum of the decimal part of the working hours, converts it to an integer (to represent minutes), and then divides it by 60 to convert minutes to hours.

`CONVERT(INT, SUM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), (Hours - FLOOR(Hours)) * 100))) % 60`: This part calculates the remaining minutes after converting the decimal part of working hours to minutes. It takes the modulo 60 to ensure that the minutes do not exceed 60.

Comment: Can you please add explanation to your answer?, that would be helpful.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a non-standard way of representing minutes in a decimal format you should convert the individual numbers (hours counts) to a true decimal format before adding them up:

```
SELECT SUM((hours%1)*10/6+FLOOR(hours)) as decimalHoursSum FROM hoursTable
```

The `decimalHoursSum` can then be decomposed into hours and minutes by doing something like the following

```
SELECT FLOOR(decimalHoursSum) as hours,ROUND(decimalHoursSum%1*60) as minutes
```